# Server cannot access application directory asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to access Web Site Administration Tool > security. When I click on security I got the following ***error:***

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Server
>   cannot access application directory 'C:\Users\Ramisha
>   Farrukh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\IT Help Desk]\'. The
>   directory does not exist or is not accessible because of security
>   settings.

One day before I can access it but today It gives me the error I don't know what cause this error to occur. Please anyone help me.
[image: Here is the permissions I have given to the folder]

Comment: physically that file or folder exist?

Comment: yes it exists directory is given

Comment: try to give the elevated permision to that folder , is this folder in your workspace or your own ?

Comment: my own. and I have give permissions

Comment: how you given and where  you have given the permission?

Comment: I have given these permissions to the directory given above. I also updating it with picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149668/discussion-between-rami-far-and-webruster).